# Appropriate directory to place additional files for jenkins builds?

Tags: jenkins

I have an API key, for example, that is not stored in a git repo that I'd like to copy from a directory on a build machine.  Where is the appropriate place to place these so that the jenkins user can still access them during a build.  The host OS is ubuntu server and jenkins home is located at path /var/lib/jenkins.

Should these be placed and copied from /opt? from /var/lib/jenkins? from /var/lib/jenkins/userContent?  What is accessible during a build?

Comment: [userContent](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/User+Content) does not seem like an appropriate place

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this should be a Jenkins build parameter. 
Use a parameterized Jenkins build and specify the API key as a string param?